# Function will not return

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I hope you can help me. This function loadUserData() does not want to execute anything in return.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { Alert, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

    export const UPDATE_USERID = 'UPDATE_USERID'


    export const loadUserData = (uid) => {
        console.log()
        return async (dispatch, getState) => {
            try {
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_USERID, payload: uid})
                const { userid } = getState().auth
                console.log("Userid:")
                console.log(userid)

            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

loadUserData is used in this function.

```
export const signin = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = getState().auth
            console.log("Email: " + email + " Password: " + password)
            console.log(ApiBaseUrl + "/users/login")
            axios.post("http://xxxxxxxxxx/users/login",
                {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                },
                {
                }
            ).then((response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))
                    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_JAVAWEBTOKEN, payload: response.data.user.token })
                    //Here 
                    loadUserData(response.data.user._id)
                }

            })

        }
        catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        }
    }

}
```

it would be nice if you could help me with my problem.

Best
Nick

Comment: Well, Nick which function exactly and what do you want to return? you have two functions here and the second one returns a function that doesn't return anything. If that's the one you want to return something then return something.

Comment: @SecondSon the second function should save the USERID in Redux. In other functions it works the same way... I ask myself why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Can you show where `loadUserData` is being used?

Comment: Hi, @khan I posted it as an answer  :)

Comment: @NickLenke, instead of posting it as an answer, please edit your question to include any updates.

Comment: @khan sorry, I changed it.

Comment: Invoking the function as such, `loadUserData(response.data.user._id)`, doesn't do anything since `loadUserData` **returns** a function. It's this returned function that you want invoked. It's been a while since I used Redux, but I believe you'll have to dispatch the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

loadUserData returns a function that is quite clearly never called. One quick fix would be to call it like `loadUserData(response.data.user._id)(dispatch, getState)`. Then you still have the problem of catching the exception. you have your try-catch block, but inside there's just a promise that you are not awaiting. The catch block in this case will never be executed unless you put `await` in front of `axios.post`